# How can I overwrite "Date Modified" with "Date Created" in Windows?

Tags: file, date, command-line, attributes

I have a system running Windows server and I have access to Powershell, VBA etc.

I need a way to overwrite the "Date Modified" attribute of all files in a directory with the date from the "Date Created" attribute. There are approx 1 million files that need to be updated across 10'000 or so subdirectories, which branch off one master directory.

Is there a simple way to do this with either command line or Powershell etc?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an hybrid batch/javascript file (save it as batch, per example `touch.cmd`) that will reset the modification datetime of all the files under a starting folder, setting it to the creation datetime of the same file.

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "targetFolder=%~1"
    if not defined targetFolder set "targetFolder=%cd%"

    rem call javascript part of batch file
    cscript //nologo //e:Javascript "%~f0" /startFolder:"%targetFolder%"

    rem End of batch area. End batch execution before reaching js zone
    endlocal
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************

    if (!WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists('startFolder')) {
        // if no start folder is given, leave
        WScript.Quit(1);
    };

    // retrieve start folder
    var startFolder = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('startFolder');

    // instantiate needed components
    var fso = WScript.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    var shell = WScript.CreateObject('Shell.Application');

    // recursive function to set the ModifyDate to the CreationDate
    (function processFolder( folderPath ){
        // test for valid paths
        folderPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName((folderPath || '' ));
        if (!fso.FolderExists(folderPath)) return ;
        // retrieve a reference to the folder namespace
        var folderNS = shell.NameSpace(folderPath);
        // process files inside this folder
        for (var files = new Enumerator(fso.GetFolder( folderPath ).Files ); !files.atEnd() ; files.moveNext()){
            var file = files.item();
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine( file.Path );
            folderNS.ParseName( file.Name ).ModifyDate = file.DateCreated;
        };
        // process files under child folders
        for (var folders = new Enumerator(fso.GetFolder( folderPath ).SubFolders); !folders.atEnd() ; folders.moveNext()){
            processFolder( folders.item().Path );
        };
    })( startFolder );

    WScript.Quit(0);
```