# How can I overwrite a file's "Date created" with its "Date modified" in Windows?

Tags: file, date, batch-file, command-line, attributes

I have a [folder full of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhgDK.png) with correct Date modified times but incorrect date created times. I want to set the dateCreated file attribute to the time of the Date modified.

The closest thing I have to my solution is a batch file that sets the date modified time to the when the file was created ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/24951475/2780666 ) but I want to do the opposite. How do I do this if possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I overwrite "Date Modified" with "Date Created" in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930496/how-can-i-overwrite-date-modified-with-date-created-in-windows)

Comment: @aschipfl it's not, and he even linked the thread in his actual question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the script you found works, I would try the following.

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "targetFolder=%~1"
if not defined targetFolder set "targetFolder=%cd%"

rem call javascript part of batch file
cscript //nologo //e:Javascript "%~f0" /startFolder:"%targetFolder%"

rem End of batch area. End batch execution before reaching js zone
endlocal
exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************

if (!WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists('startFolder')) {
    // if no start folder is given, leave
    WScript.Quit(1);
};

// retrieve start folder
var startFolder = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('startFolder');

// instantiate needed components
var fso = WScript.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var shell = WScript.CreateObject('Shell.Application');

// recursive function to set the ModifyDate to the CreationDate
(function processFolder( folderPath ){
    // test for valid paths
    folderPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName((folderPath || '' ));
    if (!fso.FolderExists(folderPath)) return ;
    // retrieve a reference to the folder namespace
    var folderNS = shell.NameSpace(folderPath);
    // process files inside this folder
    for (var files = new Enumerator(fso.GetFolder( folderPath ).Files ); !files.atEnd() ; files.moveNext()){
        var file = files.item();
        WScript.StdOut.WriteLine( file.Path );
        folderNS.ParseName( file.Name ).DateCreated = file.ModifyDate;
    };
    // process files under child folders
    for (var folders = new Enumerator(fso.GetFolder( folderPath ).SubFolders); !folders.atEnd() ; folders.moveNext()){
        processFolder( folders.item().Path );
    };
})( startFolder );

WScript.Quit(0);
```

Comment: I already tried switching ModifyDate with DateCreated and it didnt change anything but the script works when you change the Date modified to the Date created.

Comment: Hmmm that is strange @Charles.  Have you been able to take a look at the filename and see is there is a DateCreated field?